# Delete previous rows in Pandas Dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delete-row

I have a dataframe with user_id and some informations about them

```
User_id   type     info
31       R*1005    no
31       R*10335   no
25       R*1005    no
25       R*243     no
25       R*4918    yes
25       R*9017    no
25       R*9015    no
46       R*9470    no
```

I want to drop previous rows from `user_id` when the column `info` is "yes".
In the case above will be like:

```
User_id   type     info
31       R*1005    no
31       R*10335   no
25       R*9017    no
25       R*9015    no
46       R*9470    no
```

How to do this in a smart way?

Comment: so once "yes" is found you only delete the previous two rows? Your output right now is the first two and the last 4 after "yes" is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: @AnnaSemjén When "yes" is found i want delete the previous rows to the same user_id where the "yes" was found. The number of previous rows to delete can variate according to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is test if at least one `yes` in group and then for this group remove previous `yes` rows:

```
m = df['info'].eq('yes')
g = m.groupby(df['User_id'])

m1 = g.transform('any')
m2 = g.cumsum().ne(0)

df = df[(~m1 | m2) & ~m]
print (df)
   User_id     type info
0       31   R*1005   no
1       31  R*10335   no
5       25   R*9017   no
6       25   R*9015   no
7       46   R*9470   no
```